# Retrieve Data From DB using PHP

Tags: php, sql

I created a database (table) in SQL similar to this.

```
   x   y   z
1  x1  y1  z1
2  x2  y2  z2
```

This is a table that I created; now I want to do some math on it using PHP.  How can I retrieve the data and perform math on it?
How to get data from the DB table and save them in PHP variables?

```
function ans($x1, $y2, $z2)
{
#a = x1 - y2;
#z2 = $z2 -$a;
}
```

Comment: are you asking about how to execute select query ??

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  How did you create the table and load the data?

Comment: i am using www.000webhost.com , first i created db in sql than i use phpmyadmin .

Answer (score 1):

The code will look as follow:

```
<?php

 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

mysql_select_db("database", $con);

$xAnswer = 0;
$yAnswer = 0;
$zAnswer = 0;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT x,y,z FROM MathTable");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
     $xAnswer = Add($row["x"],$row["y"]);
     $yAnswer = Multiply($row["z"],$row["y"]);
     $zAnswer = Subtract($row["z"],$row["x"]);
   }

mysql_close($con);


    function Add($x,$y)
    {
       return $x + $y;
    }

    function Subtract($x,$y)
    {
       return $x-$y;
    }

    function Multiply($x,$y)
    {
       return $x*$y;
    }

    function Divide($x,$y)
    {
       return $x/$y;
        }
 ?>
```

Alternatively one can handle the math in the sql as well as follow and then just pull the answers into a variable:

```
SELECT (x+y) AS Add,(x-y) AS Subtract,(z/x) AS Divide FROM MathTable
```

The the loop through the recordsset will be as follow

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
       {
         $xAnswer = $row["Add"];
         $yAnswer = $row["Subtract"];
         $zAnswer = $row["Divide "];
       }
```

Remember that the variables will have a different answer everytime the loop increments because of the amount of records in the table so you might want a running total or alternatively you can keep running total inside using the above Add example variables:

```
$xAnswer = $xAnswer  + $row["Add"];
```

Comment: Please ensure that all the casting of variables are also taken into account. To do math strings must be coverted to int or float, etc

Comment: thanks for your answer it helped me alot . can you tell me how can i access specific elements in a table from lot of rows . by using  . SELECT X_colm FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID= 2;     SELECT Y_colm FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID=6;    i want some thing like this  ... You USed while loop it will continue in series .can i access specific row with this .

Comment: thanks alot i figered it out GUYS                          $result = mysql_query("SELECT x,y,z FROM MathTable WHERE id =4");                                                       $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT x,y,z FROM MathTable WHERE id=56");                                                            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);                              $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);                              $xAnswer = Add($row["x"],$row2["y"]);
$yAnswer = Multiply($row2["z"],$row["y"]);
$zAnswer = Subtract($row2["z"],$yAnswer);                            should i use it

Answer (score 0):

mysql_connect is going to be deprecate. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

use mysqli instead 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php